# Unexpected incorrect usage notice for Mockery_0_wpdb

Tags: php, mocking

I get this on the test function after the one that seems to create the error:

```
Test  tests/wpunit/AdminUtilitiesTest.php:testQueryDbForNewSelection
Unexpected incorrect usage notice for Mockery_0_wpdb
```

.

```
class AdminUtilitiesTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\WPTestCase {

public function tearDown() {
        \Mockery::close();

      // then
      parent::tearDown();
    }

    // tests

    public function testGlobals() {
      global $wpdb;

    // commenting the next 3 full statements fixes/hides the error
      $wpdb = \Mockery
        ::mock('\WPDB')
        ->makePartial();
      $wpdb
        ->shouldReceive('mockMethod')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(23);

      $this->assertEquals(23, $wpdb->mockMethod());
      \Mockery::close();  // removing this extra call doesn't do anything    
    }

    public function testQueryDbForNewSelection() {
      $adminUtilitiesMock = \Mockery
        ::mock('AdminUtilities')
        ->makePartial();
      $adminUtilitiesMock
        ->shouldReceive('loadTargets')
        ->andReturn(17);

      $this->assertEquals(17, $adminUtilitiesMock::loadTargets());


    }
}


// loadTargets() from the target file
  public static function loadTargets() {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = $wpdb->get_results(
      "select * from {$wpdb->prefix}fvc
        limit {$_POST['limit']}
        offset {$_POST['resultMarker']}
    ");

    return $query;
  }
```

Seems like something is wrong with test isolation. I don't think that Mockery::close() is doing anything.

I see this in the Mockery docs:

> Mockery was designed as a simple-to-use standalone mock object
>   framework, so its need for integration with any testing framework is
>   entirely optional. To integrate Mockery, we need to define a
>   tearDown() method for our tests containing the following (we may use a
>   shorter \Mockery namespace alias):

```
public function tearDown() {
    \Mockery::close();
}
```

Also tried:

Setting `global $wpdb` inside `testQueryDbForNewSelection()`. Didn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing the global variable declaration:

```
public function testGlobals() {
  // global $wpdb; // this line was removed

  $wpdb = \Mockery
    ::mock('\WPDB')
    ->makePartial();
  $wpdb
    ->shouldReceive('mockMethod')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn(23);

  $this->assertEquals(23, $wpdb->mockMethod());
  \Mockery::close();     
}
```